# Rotate Bits Right operation in Ruby

Tags: ruby, bitwise-operators

Is there a Rotate Bits Right in Ruby ?

Or how can I do that please.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to give more details than that.

Comment: a function that mades : ror(0x08048586,1) => 0x86080485

Comment: I have to say that that's still incredibly unclear - instead of assuming everyone knows what you're trying to achieve, give a little context and explain how/what/why and what you've tried to do so far.

Comment: Oh ... `ROR` = _Rotate Right_ and *not* _Ruby on Rails_. If you change "ROR" to "Rotate Bits Right" then you'll get a better response ;)

Comment: That makes far more sense - I was reading it as Ruby on Rails

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some facts:

- Ruby has operators `<<` and `>>` to shift, but no built-in rotate operator. You have to fake it.
- Ruby's `Fixnum` class automatically promotes to `Bignum` when the value exceeds the machine word size. This includes numbers that would fit in an unsigned word but not a signed word -- for example, `0xffffffff` is a positive `Bignum`, not a negative `Fixnum`.

So if you want a rotate operation, you a) have to write it using the shift operators, b) either hardcode 32 or 64 bits or ask `Fixnum` for the word size, and c) accept that the result might end up being a `Bignum`.

That being said, this might work:

```
class Integer
  def ror count
    (self >> count) | (self << (32 - count)) & 0xFFFFFFFF
  end
end
```

```
>> printf "0x%x\n", (0x01234567.ror 4)
0x70123456
```

Comment: `0xFFFFFFFF` can be replaced with `('1'*32).to_i(2)` for 32 bits, so it's no longer hard-coded.

Comment: ('1'*32).to_i(2) is not a good idea. It does cast, a slow operation.
Better to use something like 2**32-1

Answer (score 1):

If you need higher performance, and don't mind adding a dependency, there is the `bit-twiddle` gem, which provides this operation implemented in native code:

```
require 'bit-twiddle/core_ext'
# rotate by 8 bits
0x08048586.rrot32(8).to_s(16) # => "86080485"
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of this gem.

Comment: This gem does not install on windows (or from the issue on Mac). While it looks like it has a nice interface, it's not usable for me at the moment

Comment: @LukeChadwick Let me have a look and see if I can fix it on Windows.

Comment: @LukeChadwick, I have just released a new version which works on OS X. Could you check whether it can be installed on Windows now?

Answer (score -1):

ROR is rotate right.

Here's a [C implementation](http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=320) that could be ported to Ruby.

Ruby does have the

- <<    Bitwise Shift Left and
- > > Bitwise Shift Right

operators