# What does the following line of Ruby Do? "integer >> integer"

Tags: c#, ruby, translate

I am trying to convert some Ruby code into C# but I do not understand what the following line does. Specifically the "challenge >> 24" and similar parts.

```
challenge = sprintf("%c%c%c%c".encode("ASCII-8BIT"), x(challenge >> 24), x(challenge >> 16), x(challenge >> 8), x(challenge >> 0))
```

challenge is an integer that is defined earlier in the code.
x is a method that takes an integer argument and returns an integer.

I am not expecting anyone to convert it to c# for me, just an explanation would be fine.
Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit-shift to the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>>` is **Binary Right Shift Operator.**

The left operands value is moved right by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

This may be helpful: [Rotate Bits Right operation in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476969/rotate-bits-right-operation-in-ruby)

Comment: In other words, it divides by 2^24

Comment: If they struggle understanding a shift I doubt they need a rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Bit shift to the right, with the number to the right of the `>>` indicating how many times to shift.

C# has the `>>` operator too so translating that should be straightforward.