# String to BigNum and back again (in Ruby) to allow circular shift

Tags: ruby, cryptography, bit-manipulation, bignum

As a personal challenge I'm trying to implement the SIMON block cipher in Ruby. I'm running into some issues finding the best way to work with the data. The full code related to this question is located at: https://github.com/Rami114/Personal/blob/master/Simon/Simon.rb

SIMON requires both XOR, shift and circular shift operations, the last of which is forcing me to work with BigNums so I can perform the left circular shift with math rather than a more complex/slower double loop on byte arrays.

Is there a better way to convert a string to a BigNum and back again.

String -> BigNum (where N is 64 and pt is a string of plaintext)

```
 pt = pt.chars.each_slice(N/8).map {|x| x.join.unpack('b*')[0].to_i(2)}.to_a
```

So I break the string into individual characters, slice into N-sized arrays (the word size in SIMON) and unpack each set into a BigNum. That appears to work fine and I can convert it back.

Now my SIMON code is currently broken, but that's more the math I think/hope and not the code. The conversion back is (where ct is an array of bignums representing the ciphertext):

```
ct.map { |x| [x.to_s(2).rjust(128,'0')].pack('b*') }.join
```

I seem to have to right-justify pad the string as bignums are of undefined width so I have no leading 0s. Unfortunately the pack requires the defined with to have sensible output.

Is this a valid method of conversion? Is there a better way? I'm not sure on either count and hoping someone here can help out.

E: For @torimus, the circular shift implementation I'm using (From link above)

```
def self.lcs (bytes, block_size, shift)
  ((bytes << shift) | (bytes >> (block_size - shift))) & ((1<< block_size)-1)
end
```

Comment: Should that be `.rjust(64,'0')` in the second list, or is the padding with extra nulls (that I get running a 64 char string through both your lines of code) part of the cipher algorithm?

Comment: Concerning the bit rotation operation following [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3477091/2352780) may come handy.

Comment: @NeilSlater the rjust is on 128 bits because the SIMON rounds work on 2 N-sized words together to form a 128 bit block.

Comment: @Torimus Added the circular shift code I'm using in the original question. It's using an identical mechanism to that in your link answers (thanks though) but a bit more flexibly to allow for varying width.

Comment: This is an alternative to your first line: `pt.scan( /.{#{N/8}}/ ).map { |x| x.unpack('b*')[0].to_i(2) }.to_a`. It avoids creating then joining a temporary array, at the expense of using a simple regex - I don't think it's a big improvement (or necessarily an improvement), although I would expect it to be slightly faster, so perhaps worth benchmarking

Comment: Noticed some issues in my key_expansion stage. I'm going to go at it slow and write it in C first (which is much easier) then make sure each component works in turn.

Answer (score 0):

If you would be equally happy with `unpack('B*')` with msb first binary numbers (which you could well be if all your processing is circular), then you could also use `.unpack('Q>')` instead of `.unpack('B*')[0].to_i(2)` for generating `pt`:

```
pt = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM1234567890!@"

# Your version (with 'B' == msb first) for comparison:
pt_nums = pt.chars.each_slice(N/8).map {|x| x.join.unpack('B*')[0].to_i(2)}.to_a
=> [8176115190769218921, 8030025283835160424, 7668342063789995618, 7957105551900562521,
  6145530372635706438, 5136437062280042563, 6215616529169527604, 3834312847369707840]

# unpack to 64-bit unsigned integers directly
pt_nums =  pt.unpack('Q>8')
=> [8176115190769218921, 8030025283835160424, 7668342063789995618, 7957105551900562521, 
  6145530372635706438, 5136437062280042563, 6215616529169527604, 3834312847369707840]
```

There are no native 128-bit pack/unpacks to return in the other direction, but you can use `Fixnum` to solve this too:

```
split128 = 1 << 64
ct = pt # Just to show round-trip
ct.map { |x| [ x / split128, x % split128 ].pack('Q>2') }.join

=> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00qwertyui . . . " # truncated
```

This avoids a lot of the temporary stages on your code, but at the expense of using a different byte coding - I don't know enough about SIMON to comment whether this is adaptable to your needs.

Comment: Note there was a bug in first version of this, the split point is `1 << 64` not 65 as initially written.